# Y axis locked on a mirrored object

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, mirror

I've run into this problem several times. I cant work in blender anymore because it happens every time I try to sculpt. It seems that once I mirror a plane it decides that the y axis isn't a thing anymore. I need someone to tell me what is wrong.
[image: blender showing the object's y axis error]

Comment: Is your object rotated? It could be that the mirror modifier is really acting on the Y axis, and with clipping enabled, it would clamp all verts at 0 to 0

Comment: Could be zero (or near zero) scale on an axis.

Comment: gandalf3 you mean the mesh.

Comment: @Yvain hm? What do you mean?

Comment: gandlaf3, the Mirror modifier is local, so whatever the rotation of the object it will produce the same effect, moving the mesh has an influence though